# Does operator precedence matter for && and == in javascrtipt?

Tags: javascript, operators, operator-precedence

More specifically, is there a set of values ( a, b and c) for which the operator precedence matters in the statement:

```
var value = (a && b == c);
```

(with the exception of NaN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

```
js> false && true == false
false
js> (false && true) == false
true
```

Since `==` has higher precedence than `&&`, the first is parsed as `false && (true == false)`, which is equivalent to `false && false`, and thus evaluates to `false`. The second is equivalent to `false == false`, which is `true`

Comment: I'm using spidermonkey http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/ I don't use it for all that much, just testing the occasional expression like this.

Comment: Yes. Safari & Chrome also have JavaScript consoles courtesy of the WebKit Inspector http://webkit.org/blog/197/web-inspector-redesign/

Answer (score 2):

The language is parsed such that your statement is the equivalent of `(a && (b == c))`.  The equality operator will always run before `&&`, `||` and other logical operators.  You can find the nitty-gritty details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: Yeah I understand that but I was trying to figure out if it made a difference in that specific example.

Answer (score 2):

Yup.  `==` binds more tightly than `&&`, so what you have binds as

```
var val = a && ( b == c)
```

See [here](http://www.codehouse.com/javascript/precedence/).  So `a==0`, `b==1` and `c==0` is false, while `(a&&b)==c` is true.

(Fixed typo.  Dammit.)

Comment: a=1, b=0, c=0 in

a && b == c 

would give 1 && (0 == 0) => 1 && true => true